# load data WITHOUT double-quotes

Tags: mysql

I am loading data that looks like this (URL removed)

```
"shortUrl"|"url"|"date"|"ipAddr"|"userAgent"|"referrer"
"http://clk2.it/uHamBX"|"http://..."|"2017-05-21T16:14:49.590Z"|"97.33.66.11"|"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A523 Safari/8536.25"|""
```

like so

```
mysql -h <host> -u <user> --password=<password> --local-infile <db> -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/data/<file>.csv' INTO TABLE <table> FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' IGNORE 1 LINES"
```

It works fine but the problem is that data is loaded WITH the double-quotes like so (URL removed)

```
shortUrl, url, date, ipAddr, userAgent, referrer
"http://clk2.it/CPJK2c", "http://...", "2017-05-18T17:12:22.278Z", "96.8.170.62", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/601.2.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0.1 Safari/601.2.4 facebookexternalhit/1.1 Facebot Twitterbot/1.0", ""
"http://clk2.it/CPJK2c", "http://...", "2017-05-18T17:12:45.500Z", "96.8.170.62", "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.1.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14E304 Safari/602.1", ""
"http://clk2.it/CPJK2c", "http://...", "2017-05-18T17:13:44.015Z", "96.8.170.62", "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.1.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14E304 Safari/602.1", ""
```

Is there a way to load data WITHOUT double-quotes?

Comment: `...FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' ENCLOSED BY '"'`

Comment: Nope. I have tried that. No change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me. Notice screening in `'\"'`.

```
cat >data.csv

"shortUrl"|"url"|"date"|"ipAddr"|"userAgent"|"referrer"
"http://clk2.it/uHamBX"|"http://..."|"2017-05-21T16:14:49.590Z"|"97.33.66.11"|"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A523 Safari/8536.25"|""
^D

mysql -u <user> --password=<password> --local-infile <db> -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/data.csv' INTO TABLE t1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' enclosed by '\"' IGNORE 1 LINES"
```

> mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be
>   insecure.

```
mysql -u <user> -p <db> -e 'select * from t1'

| shorturl              | url        | date1                    | ip          | useragent                                                                                                                               | referrer |
+-----------------------+------------+--------------------------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| http://clk2.it/uHamBX | http://... | 2017-05-21T16:14:49.590Z | 97.33.66.11 | Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A523 Safari/8536.25 |          |
+-----------------------+------------+--------------------------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
```

Comment: It works for me too. The escaping on the double quotes did the trick. Accepted and voted up. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use ENCLOSED BY and ESCAPED BY

```
FIELDS
    TERMINATED BY '|'
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    ESCAPED BY ''
```

Comment: No change. My  data is still loaded WITH the double-quotes. `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'usDpvk.csv' INTO TABLE click_data FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '' IGNORE 1 LINES" `